# Exact string search in array in Elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, string, elasticsearch

I want to search exact string in array.
My data in ES is like below:

```
         { category": [
              "abc test"
           ],
           "es_flag": false,
           "bullet_points": [],
           "content": "",
           "description": false }
```

I have multiple category like "abc test", "new abc test" etc...

I am trying below query but I am getting multiple category result, I was searching for "abc test" but "new abc test" category is also coming in the result.

```
    {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 30,
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must": [
                { "match_phrase": { "category": "abc test" } }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [ { "createdAt": { "order": "desc" } } ]
}
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using default analyzer. In that case `match_phrase` against `"field": "abc test"` will match all documents which will have the fields with adjacent tokens of `abc test`, including:

- `new abc test`
- `abc test new`
- `foo abc test bar`

And it will not match:

- `abc new test` - query tokens are not adjacent
- `test abc` - query tokens are adjacent, but in the wrong order

What would actually help you is using the `keyword` analyzer for your field (you either need to build new index from scratch or update your mappings). If you're building from scrach:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_index -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "categories": {
      "properties": {
        "category": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And afterwards you need to use just simple query, e.g. like this (either `match` or `term` will do):

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "abc test"
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am not able to update existing property.
{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
  {
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "No handler for type [text] declared on field [category]"
}
],
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "No handler for type [text] declared on field [category]"
},
"status": 400
}

I am getting above error while updating the index.

Comment: It might be "string" as well - depending on ES version. Which ES version are u using?

Answer (score 0):

My version of elasticsearch is 6.0.1. I am using this approach:

```
GET <your index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "query_string": {
          "query": "category:abc OR category:test"
        }
      }]
    }    
  },
  "sort":[{"createdAt": {
    "order": "desc"
  }}]
}
```